# What's the difference between "annualised" and "annual"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Both "annualised" and "annual" function as an adjective.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: By the way,please,don't block me from asking questions.i have no any teacher who could teach me english.. This english website is only one stuff i could rely on..just let me know if i make some unacceptable mistakes.and i will behave myself sincerely.

Comment: although the website warned me. but i still cannot figire out what kind of mistake i made on this site

Comment: The block warning is automatic. We didn't send it to you. It was sent to you because your questions didn't receive many upvotes (or generally positive responses) from the community. Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236800/quality-ban-warning). The only thing you need to do is to ask better, more well formulated questions.

Answer (score 1):

Annualized is a financial term meaning that a figure has been changed from one number to another number (using math) in order to show the yearly rate instead of some other rate (daily, monthly, quarterly).

Annual means "yearly" or every year. You can have an annual festival or an annual meeting.

Annualized is a finance word. Annual is more often used in normal vocabulary. You're more likely to use "annual" than "annualized," unless you're in finance.